# SQL Server - update underlying table Record from View AFTER INSERT

Tags: sql-server, triggers, calculated-columns, sql-view

This is my first time asking a question on here, I have gotten many answers to my questions just browsing though - so thanks folks for that, but this time I am stuck.

I am mostly new to SQL so bear with me and I am also working with a SQL Server 2008 R2 database not designed by me, I am just trying to get data out of it for other uses, I also use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

SETUP: There are many tables but in this case I am working with one main specific `Items` table and 5 other "joined" tables and a view created from those tables. I then use the view in MS Access which I am more familiar with, I have added some new columns to the main table and one of them I want to store a computed `MachineRate` of the specific `Item` based on values of the main table (same record) and the other tables. I was able to do all of this fine on the view.

But my question is this: would it be possible to have this computed value used as the default value of the main table or fired in there with a trigger?

I have tried functions and triggers and am starting to wonder if this will not work, and as mentioned the view is based on the table I want to insert the value into.

For ex (this is just partial) : main table has the following columns...

```
RecID, PartRef, Material, Width, Length, Thickness, MachRate etc
```

And  `MachineRate` table

```
RecID, Rate
```

And `TableOfTech` table

```
RecID, Material, Thickness1, Thickness2, AddToMachRate  etc...
```

Those 3 of 5 tables are needed for my computed value, the main table's `MachRate` value needs to be (Rate from MachineRate + AddToMachRate from TableOfTech) where  TableOfTech.Material = MainTable.Material and MainTable.Thickness between TableOfTech.Thickness1 and Thickness2

Not sure how much the ex: really helps, but to give u an idea what I am working with, so does it really work to insert into a table column on ONLY the NEW record being inserted... a value based on a View from the SAME table ?

And I better explain why I want to do this....In this case it is necessary for the users to be able to change that value but for the most part defaults will be ok and we are using it like that at the moment

I hope this makes sense to you guys, I look forward to any help !

S. Brubacher

Comment: You *could* create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view, so that if an `INSERT` on that view happens, you get "notified" and you can then decide what to do with the values being inserted into the view - how to store them into the underlying tables

Comment: marc, thanks for replying - I have fooled around with an Instead Of Insert trigger but I get the default value in the field of the table, I have a default value set on the column as it does not allow nulls, just while testing, see below
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_PopMachRateSQL]
ON dbo.Qry_AllParts2
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.PPRR_PPRR_00000100
SET dbo.PPRR_PPRR_00000100.MachRateSQL = UseRate
FROM inserted AS i
WHERE dbo.PPRR_PPRR_00000100.RecID = i.RecID
END

Comment: Muhammed Ali
Not sure if I am posting/replying in the right place... ?

I realize what you are saying but what I want to is make sure that value never changes anyway unless I run an update query from inside Access, so In other words If I ever change data on one of those to 2 tables which has data for the computed column I want to pop up a message box and ask if the Main Item records need to be updated based on my machine rate change or not
Maybe I am not thinking of everything yet ?

Comment: I dont think you can achieve this in Access "A pop up message" everytime you update a record. But the question is do you really need all this burden just to see a computed column ?? see my answer below I have advised two very simple solution for this View OR Indexed Views, and trust me you should avoid trigger as much as you can.

Comment: Muhammed - I have heard triggers are not the best, I am just trying to make this as automated as possible since the data is all there anyway, its just I am working with a Database on a program we are using and I cant just do whatever with the tables I wish, I already have the computed value on the View which I assume is what u mean by "at runtime" ? I just cant get it to insert that value into the Main table AFTER INSERT or INSTEAD OF INSERT

Comment: I did get it finally, Just needed to use the references to inserted table properly, see how I like it - thanks all for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a scenario where you have a computed column in a table it is best to keep all the column from where the value is being computed for this computed column in that same table.

You can have computed column whos value is being computed from columns from other tables but than you have to create `INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers, AFTER UPDATE, AFTER DELETE` triggers on all tables from where the value is being computed  to sync the computed column for any changes in the source table, which can be a hell of task and Triggers can be silent killers at times.

So to avoid all this hassle just keep the columns from where the values are being computed and the computed column it self in One table.

Another even simpler option will be to create another `view` which gathers data at run time from these multiple underlying tables and compute them at runtime for you. Since you already have the data in you database from where this column is being computed its better to compute them at runtime only when you want to see the computed results.

If you have lots of data in your underlying tables and computing them values at run time takes a lot of time then consider `INDEXED VIEWS`.

My suggestion would be avoid as much as possible to have a situation where you have a computed column and source columns in multiple tables.